# What does " he feels the liability to be able to answerable to someone " means?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, usage

Just need the explanation of what does this sentence actually mean ? And how can be be used

Answer (score 1):

**"he feels the liability to be able to answerable to someone**"

This sentence makes no sense to me, so I will edit it

**He feels the liability of being answerable to someone**

---

This means

**he experiences the responsibility of being answerable to someone**

---

**liability** noun (RESPONSIBILITY); the fact that someone is legally responsible for something:
He denies any liability for the damage caused.

**feel** verb (EXPERIENCE); to experience something physical or emotional:

All ref CED [liability](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/liability)   [Feels][2